# makefile linking and relinking issues

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I'd like that my makefile stopped linking every time I call it if the .o file is already up-to-date.
Do you have any ideas about it?

Here is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra

RM      = rm -f

NAME    = ft_display_file

SRCS    = ft_display_file.c

OBJS    = ${SRCS:.c=.o}

all:        $(NAME)

${NAME}:    ${OBJS}

clean:
            ${RM} ${OBJS}

fclean:     clean
            ${RM} $(NAME)

re:         fclean all
```

Thanx,
Fab

Comment: What are you running? If you just type `make` and then `make` again are you claiming it is re-linking on the second invocation? That shouldn't be happening based on that makefile shown. Please provide a full run log.

Comment: What you seem to be describing is a core part of `make`'s standard behavior, and I don't see anything in the makefile presented that would interfere with it.

Comment: here's a link to the image https://imgur.com/a/Vs95SqR
Now I wonder whether the problem comes from the use of powershell. I'm gonna try to run it with ubuntu

Comment: Solved it, it comes from powershell. Thank you so much